# Drupal Module Development :  Uninstall/Reinstall/Repeat?

Tags: drupal, module, reinstall

I'm developing a custom module for Drupal on my local machine.

When I edit my code, the changes are never applied right away. So, I go to Administer Modules, and uninstall, and then reinstall my module. This is cycle of uninstall-install-develop-repeat  is slow and tedious.

Is there a better way to do it?

My module makes extensive use of Drupal framework so I'm not sure developing it exclusively in PHP first is an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would highly recommend installing the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel).  It is very useful while developing for Drupal. Once installed, you can enable the Devel block which is *extremely* useful. It has a list of links to perform somewhat tedious tasks faster, such as emptying the cache, reinstalling modules, rebuilding the menus, etc.

Many of the changes to your module should not require visiting the modules page. You mostly see the need to do this when you are changing the menu with [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) in your module, as the menus are only rebuilt when visiting that page (or using Devel block "Rebuild Menus" link ;) )

Comment: In addition, I can strongly suggest Drush, which leverages these devel commands to the commandline. `$ drush cc all` to flush all cache.

Comment: Using the devel module with Drush gives you `drush devel-reinstall myModule` which effectively disables, uninstalls, re-installs, enables, and clears the cache (I think) for the modules that you specify.

Answer (score 3):

When uninstall/install, the only things that is executed is what is in .install file.

If you don't change this file, you don't have to uninstall/install the module.

Maybe your problem is just a cache issue. Drupal strongly cache a lot a things. And when you enable a module, the cache is cleared. You can clear you cache manually.

On an other hand, I recommand to look on [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) that allow you to do those things faster. (clear cache, enable/disable a module/...)

Comment: Note that during *disabling* the uninstall intructions in `.install` are **not** ran. Only during uninstallation. Disabling is when you uncheck a module on its module page and press save. uninstalling is then possible trough the "uninstall" tab on that same module page.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal admin menu (http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) along with [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) comes in very handy if you have to flush caches.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop cache on each time when you edit your code

**Administer->Site perfomance**

Comment: What the poster is asking about is not the same as clearing cache.

Answer (score 0):

How can re-install module using Drush commands ? 
Run command
`drush dre cars_api`
For details visit
 
https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/devel/devel:reinstall/

========================   Drush For  Drupal ========================

What is Drush ?
Ans :  Drush is a command line shell and scripting interface for Drupal,
 and it is work like
          Laravel-Artisan, and Angular CLi etc.
           It is very Help-full for fast development on Drupal.
          Official Website  ->    http://www.drush.org/
          Official composer repository  -> https://packagist.org/packages/drush/drush#dev-master
          Official Drupal Repository ->  https://www.drupal.org/project/drush

What is the Installation Process ?
Ans : There is following steps.
1.Step
Install new and latest version of composer 
   2. Step 
        Run in vscode  Terminal
`composer global require drush/drush:9.x-dev`
check the installation  in terminal  via following command
`drush version`
For more details visit 
https://packagist.org/packages/drush/drush#dev-master
And also helpful
http://docs.drush.org/en/master/
3. Step
Visite following link and see Drush All conads details and documentation
https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/
https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/prevent-cache-clear.html

How can resolve Drush Errors ?
Run command in vscode terminal
`Composer require drush/drush`

How can see drush commands list in terminal ?
Just type in vscode terminal in project dir
`Drush`
and enter
So all commands will be listed with summary

Uninstallation process for  Drush ?
Just change in command ‘require’ to ‘remove’
`composer global remove drush/drush:9.x-dev`

Comment: (Review) Thanks for this answer, but please do not simply copy external documentation snippets into your answer. Especially not items that are not directly relevant to the question. And in general: please have a look at the formatting help near the input box to make your answer more readable ;)

Comment: Thanks for appreciate !
i will try my best in next contribution to the community.